# Electrical - converting 3-way to single pole for multiple fixtures

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

My kitchen has 4 ceiling lights that are all on a 3-way switch (one switch at each end of the room). I would like to separate them and put 2 lights on one switch (single pole) and 2 lights on the other switch (single pole).

Can someone provide a wiring diagram for this?

The house was recently professionally rewired (before we bought it) so I'm hoping everything looks nice and tidy once I open up the boxes.

Thanks!

Comment: What you propose *may* require running additional cables, depending on how it's wired. To help us help you. Turn off the power at the breaker, then open up each box (switches, lights). Then list all the wires in each box, and how they're connected (or include a photo of the wiring in each box).

Answer (score 1):

Three way switches offer a convenience that is sometimes not appreciated until you eliminate them and then are living without them.

One thing to consider if you are trying to split these four light fixtures into two in order to have times when your whole kitchen is not blaring in full light is to consider a different approach. You could replace these two 3-way switches with 3-way type dimmer switches.

This could give you want you want, reduced lighting, whilst being able to use the existing in place wiring. Depending upon device selection you could also get the ability to control the lights remotely.